# Understanding the use of views in a Multi-Device Project

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

This is the first time I have really attempted a Project using Firemonkey, with the Target Platform been Android.

I am finding it difficult trying to understand the workflow with the use of views been somewhat trivial, I just can't seem to grasp the concept at the moment.

I have successfully managed to get the Delphi IDE to recognise my device (Xperia Z2) so when building and running the Project I can see the app on my phone (although so far I am not too impressed, long black screens before anything showing and sometimes the app wont show at all, not to mention slow compilation and linking time).

The first problem I ran into is that controls dont appear on the Android device in the correct places. I added `Android 5" Phone` as a view as that would be the closest thing to my device, the controls on the Form Designer are aligned to how I want them, for simple testing I just dropped a couple of buttons that are centered in the middle of the form horizontally. When running and viewing the app on my phone however, the buttons are wider than the visible area of the phone, I tried the same with other views such as `Android 4" Phone` and it's the same. The controls appear lined up correctly on the Delphi Form Designer, but when running and viewing them on my phone they are not lined up at all, it feels like I need to guess where the controls should appear making views seem pointless, after all I cannot test on a multitude of devices and therefore if they don't appear on my phone as they do on the Delphi Form Designer what hope do we have? I expected that how the controls appeared in the view window is exactly how it should appear on my Android deivce but this does not seem the case.

The other view related question is, what is the purpose of the Master View? From my vague understanding you need views to design the layout for each Android device, does this mean then for each device view we have to constantly reposition and move controls independantly for each view? What purpose does the master view have, other than from what I can tell you can only delete controls from the master view and from each view use the `Revert to Inherited` context menu.

It feels like I need to guess where the controls should appear, the device view at Design Time seems rather inaccurate, surely how you look at the device view on the Form Designer is exactly how it should appear on your Android device?

Comment: Usually, you put your controls inside Layout components which automatically adjust to size and this allows for keeping things in order for different phone sizes. Their are even Layouts that shrink and expand components to fit.

Comment: Rule of thumb is don't use views from the beginning. Wait until your app's logic is solid and all your controls are in place and working in the master view. Then you create a view for everything you want to support. It's best to do all your initial designs as small as possible as to fit the smallest screen. Then, as you create each view, make any needed adjustments on that view. I've noticed the more views you have created, the more sluggish the IDE becomes. So don't create a view unless you actually want to use it. Every view inherits from the master view (and actually saves a new file).

Comment: @DougRudd Thanks for the tip I will make sure to start using layout controls now.

Comment: @JerryDodge Some good tips there thanks very much :) What is a preferable size do you think when working in the master view? Default is 640x480 if I remember correctly, is it best to keep it like that and as you said before get as much done in the master view before handling individual views?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact size, I tend to develop in a larger size anyway but constantly check to make sure things are fitting properly. Just scale it to the size of a 3.5" device.

Comment: @JerryDodge this is going to take some developing an Android app, the use of views kind of seems pointless as they are not a true representation when run on an android device. Then it feels like a massive pain having to do what feels like redesigning your project to suit several different device types, why they didn't allow one view fits all devices I do not know, but my initial impression of Android development in Delphi seems rather tedious, maybe it will get better as times goes by I don't know but it definitely feels like a lot of work getting a project up and running.

Comment: Because iOS and Android are extremely different when it comes to how controls are scaled and displayed. Also keep in mind Delphi supported iOS long before Android was recently introduced, so a lot of the fundamentals of Firemonkey are based around how iOS works, and further adapted to also work on Android.

Comment: I think views are only meant to give you a preview of the real thing and provide device-specific modifications apart from the master view. However yes, it is rather lame how in the end it scales differently anyway. I've become friends with the `Scale` property of controls. I don't think the reason is to change scale - but rather to change layouts, because iOS and Android have different preferred layouts.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thanks for your help. My worry is I could spend all the time in the world getting the app looking right on my device only to later find that the app looks completely wrong on other devices. Seems like you need to take extra special care with layouts as Doug Rudd mentioned and with scaling you touched upon. Oh the joys of Android development!

Comment: Oh the joys of multi-platform development... I do all my development and debugging on Windows, and periodically test it on mobile... Turns out a TListViewItem.Tag property can't handle pointers to objects on iOS or Android. So I'm in the process of implementing a whole List View Manager unit to not only allow easily attaching objects, but also managing groups of items within a group (under a header item).

Comment: And it's not working out that well either:  http://oi60.tinypic.com/20k6hbd.jpg